# cast device discovery won't work with my application ID

Tags: java, android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm very new to the google cast sdk and I have registered a app on the cast developer console with a style media receiver. My idea is to send images to the chromecast device from an android application.
I have tried a few examples and tried writing my own now and following is the code snippets I have used to get the device discovered. but it doesn't seem to work. I have set the correct permissions in the manifest as well but I can't get the cast button to display on the action bar for some reason.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(
            android.R.color.transparent));


    mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
    //.addControlCategory(
    //CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID).build();

    .addControlCategory(
            CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.app_id))).build();

    mMediaRouterCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Start media router discovery
    mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
            MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
}       

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (isFinishing()) {
        // End media router discovery
        mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
    // Set the MediaRouteActionProvider selector for device discovery.
    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID` as your appId makes the cast button visible but using your own appId doesn't, then it means your cast device is not registered correctly for your application. If that is the case, you need to make sure the correct serial number has been used in the developer console and you have the "send serial number ..." checkbox checked when you set up your chromecast. After doing all of this, reboot your chromecast so it can pick up the new configuration.

Comment: Well its all setup. I can use other applicarions from the github

Comment: You didn't answer my question: does it work when you only change your app id to DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID and no other changes?

Comment: No it doesn't. I tried adding .addControlCategory(
  CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID).build(); in the code but it didn't work for me

Comment: then it is not an issue with your application id, you need to look for your problem in other places in your application. Is this code identical to the one here: https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android/blob/master/src/com/example/mediarouter/MediaRouterActionBarButtonActivity.java? If so, is that working or that is not working for you either?

Comment: The code i have used is from the CastHelloText from github. But I will try your suggestion too. Also if im to send an image to the device what do I need? STM or DRM? This has been confusing me a little bit as well. Thanks

Comment: Styled and Default Receivers are the same code base, certain aspects of the styled one can be styled based on a CSS that you provide.

Comment: Thank you. I created a new project and tried working on it but still doesn't seem to discover the device. Almost giving up on it now.

Comment: just a quick question...do I have to add the showcaseview library in my project?

Comment: It depends on your own requirements. Our recommendation in UX  Guidelines/Checklist is to bring the Cast button to user's attention the first time they start the app.

Comment: The reason why I asked you why is because I don't know if my device discovery is successful and the cast button is not displaying for some reason? in case its successful is there a way for me to know if it has? eg: like toasting or something? is the showcase library required to display the cast button?

Comment: No it is not required to show the cast button. You also might want to do some search on your questions, for example see what the Showcase library is about, etc.